# Fetching entity attributes directly from coredata entity

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have an Entity called Devices in CoreData. Devices have following attributes:
Name, model, manufacturer, owner. All attributes are of string type. I am using the following code to fetch values from Entity devices using predicate

```
 NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Devices" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:entity];

request.fetchLimit = Device_LIMIT;
NSSortDescriptor *sortDisc = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"model" ascending:YES];
[request setSortDescriptors:@[sortDisc]];
NSError *error;
NSArray *array = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];   
if (array) {

    arrName = [array valueForKey:@"Name"];
}

return arrName;
```

I am getting the desired result this way.But, my question is how can I directly fetch an array from Device Entity for Name attribute, without adding any if-else or for in condition.

Comment: What is the desired result?

Comment: All values under Name attribute in Device entity.

Comment: Have you checked the `array` is having all the records from Devices Entity?

Comment: Yes,they are from Devices entity.I just want to know if core data has any property that can help to replace     arrName = [array valueForKey:@"Name"];

Comment: Do a for-loop to add the values to `arrName`

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fetch an array from Core Data to get these values-- that's just how Core Data works. You could change your code to use `NSDictionaryResultType`, but then you'd just get an array of dictionaries instead of an array of managed objects. What you're doing is correct, an there's no short cut to get name values without getting an array and extracting the names from that array.

Comment: U r the only one who really understood my question.Thanks Sir ,I have tried using NSDictionaryResultType and setPropertiesToFetch and got the results also.But I have a question after using that,is it is possible to fetch relationship attributes also this way?I mean,lets say  there is another entity Person and Person has three attributes -age,job,experience and Device has one to many relationships with car named cars,then can we fetch attributes of car also directly  using setPropertiesToFetch and NSDictionaryResultType?

Answer (score 0):

Do a for-loop to add values to `arrName` as:

```
NSMutableArray *arrName = [NSMutableArray new];

for (NSManagedObject *object in array) {
    [arrName addObject:object[@"Name"]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A nil array is only returned if the fetch request failed with an error.

Your code should be structured such that if there is no array, you should deal with the error.

EDIT: This is fairly true for most methods that return something and take an error as an argument in cocoa.  Usually if nothing is returned, then the error should be checked.

Answer (score 0):

The return value for the method `executeFetchRequest` is an objects array, so you must use a for-loop to take the name attribute out.

Comment: He's already getting the names without a `for` loop, so clearly a loop is not necessary.